# How to access root password to change date & time on Gnome [Linux]

Tags: linux, gnome

I am trying to change the time 7 date on my Linux machine. But it asks me to authenticate as root for this. I tried to enter as root as password but that was incorrect. How could I access the root password?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

If your user is in the sudo group, just use

```
sudo -s
```

to drop into a root shell

Comment: Any other possible solutions?

Comment: For security reasons, if you don't have the root password, and you are not a sudo user, the only way to recover the password is to re-set it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password